# How to use .get() within a function. Python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
import random

def Factorer(a,b,c):
    while True:
        random_a1=random.randint(-10,10)
        random_a2=random.randint(-10,10)
        random_c1=random.randint(-10,10)
        random_c2=random.randint(-10,10)
        if random_a1==0 or random_a2 == 0 or random_c1 == 0 or random_c2 == 0:
            pass
        elif (random_a1*random_c2) + (random_a2*random_c1) == b and random_a1/random_c1 != random_a2/random_c2 and random_a1*random_a2==a and random_c1*random_c2==c:
            break
    print "y=(%dx+(%d))(%dx+(%d))" % (random_a1,random_c1,random_a2,random_c2)

root = Tk()
buttonSim1 = Button(root, text="Convert", command=lambda: Factorer(enterA.get(),enterB.get(),enterC.get()))
buttonSim1.grid(row=2, column=3)
enterA = Entry(root)
enterA.grid(row=1, column=1)
enterB = Entry(root)
enterB.grid(row=1, column=2)
enterC = Entry(root)
enterC.grid(row=1, column=3)

root.mainloop()
```

How can I get this code to run, every time I click the button It just crashes.
It works however if I remove the .get() and just insert numbers.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It "just crashes"? No output? No error message whatsoever?

Comment: No output error, just crashes have to force close

Comment: So it doesn't crash but hang. You have a while-loop there, maybe it's stuck there?

Comment: Throw in some debugging output; seems like your `get` is giving you conditions that don't ever satisfy the break condition, whereas your numbers do.

Comment: You are stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: So you're trying to factor a 2nd degree polynomial by randomly guessing the components of the roots?  You should look into the [the quadratic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Solving_the_quadratic_equation) for much more efficient approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing strings to ints, you would need to cast `a,b` and `c` to int:

```
Tkinter.Button(root, text="Convert", command=lambda: Factorer(int(enterA.get()),int(enterB.get()),int(enterC.get())))
```

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is that you're comparing strings to integers, so your infinite while loop never finishes. That is why the program hands and has to be force-quit.

The best solution is to have your button call a function that gets the data, formats it to the proper value, and then calls the function to do the work. Trying to squeeze all of that into a `lambda` makes for a program that is hard to debug.

For example:

```
def on_button_click():
    a = int(enterA.get())
    b = int(enterB.get())
    c = int(enterC.get())

    result = Factorer(a,b,c)
    print(result)

Tkinter.Button(..., command=on_button_click)
```

By using a separate function, it gives you the opportunity to add print statements or pdb breakpoints so you can examine the data as it is running. It also makes it easier to add try/catch blocks to handle the case where the user didn't enter valid numbers.